# SpecFlow error: One or more step definitions are not implemented yet

Tags: c#, specflow

When I run the unit tests, I'm getting:

```
One or more step definitions are not implemented yet.
      SpecFlowFeature1Steps.GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(50)Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to remove `ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();` from all the methods:

```
    [Given(@"I have entered (.*) into the calculator")]
    public void GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(int p0)
    {
        ScenarioContext.Current.Pending(); // remove this
    }
```

I didn't realize it was causing the error and I thought it was because of missing step definitions.

Anyway, leaving this in case anyone encounters the same error in the future.